# python pip trouble installing from requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I've had great luck with pip in the past, but working at installing some stuff in a venv on is giving me some headaches.
I keep getting errors like
    No distributions at all found for somepackage Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement somepackage

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-RjqjFW/psycopg2
```

I know these packages are installed on the main system, but its like they won't work on the venv. How do you all get around this problem? It's been a long day and I just don't understand what the problem is, especially because they work on my local system, they work on the main python install on my remote system, but not in the venv for some crazy reason. Any ideas?

Here is the requirements, I thought it was alittle intense for django, but thats what pip freeze > requirements.txt gave me

```
Babel==1.3
Django==1.7.1
Fabric==1.10.1
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Babel==0.9
Flask-Login==0.2.11
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-OpenID==1.2.4
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0
Flask-WTF==0.10.3
Flask-WhooshAlchemy==0.56
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
PAM==0.4.2
Pillow==2.3.0
Pygments==1.6
Scrapy==0.24.4
Sphinx==1.2.2
Tempita==0.5.2
WTForms==2.0.1
Werkzeug==0.9.6
Whoosh==2.6.0
adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4
apt-xapian-index==0.45
argparse==1.2.1
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
blinker==1.3
boto==2.20.1
bottle==0.12.7
certifi==14.05.14
chardet==2.0.1
colorama==0.2.5
command-not-found==0.3
coverage==3.7.1
cssselect==0.9.1
debtagshw==0.1
decorator==3.4.0
defer==1.0.6
dirspec==13.10
docutils==0.11
duplicity==0.6.23
ecdsa==0.11
flipflop==1.0
guess-language==0.2
guppy==0.1.9
html5lib==0.999
httplib2==0.8
ipython==2.3.1
itsdangerous==0.24
lockfile==0.8
lxml==3.3.3
nose==1.3.4
numpy==1.8.2
oauthlib==0.6.1
oneconf==0.3.7
paramiko==1.15.2
pbr==0.10.7
pexpect==3.1
piston-mini-client==0.7.5
psycopg2==2.5.4
pyOpenSSL==0.13
pyasn1==0.1.7
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycups==1.9.66
pycurl==7.19.3
pygame==1.9.1release
pygobject==3.12.0
pyserial==2.6
pysmbc==1.0.14.1
python-apt==0.9.3.5ubuntu1
python-debian==0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2
python-openid==2.2.5
pytz==2014.10
pyxdg==0.25
queuelib==1.2.2
reportlab==3.0
requests==2.2.1
roman==2.0.0
sessioninstaller==0.0.0
simplegeneric==0.8.1
six==1.5.2
software-center-aptd-plugins==0.0.0
speaklater==1.3
sqlalchemy-migrate==0.9.2
sqlparse==0.1.14
system-service==0.1.6
tornado==4.0.2
unity-lens-photos==1.0
urllib3==1.7.1
virtualenv==1.11.6
w3lib==1.10.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
wxPython==2.8.12.1
wxPython-common==2.8.12.1
xdiagnose==3.6.3build2
z3c.xmlhttp==0.5.1
zope.interface==4.0.5
zope.publisher==4.0.0a4
zope.traversing==4.0.0
zope.viewlet==4.0.0a1
```

Comment: Can you please post your requirements.txt in your question for us to try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to install it on windows? I've never managed to install psycopg2 on windows using pip (in a virtualenv). I had to download the installer and run "path/to/venv/bins/easy_install psycopg2_package.exe".

Comment: No I am on Ubuntu. requirements is posted above

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I see a few problems:

1. Your `requirements.txt` is for the base system Python, not any virtual environment. Django does not have any external dependencies.
2. You are using the root user to install packages in your virtual environment (or you are using `sudo` when you shouldn't).

The best option is to start from scratch:

```
$ virtualenv myvenv
...
$ source myvenv/bin/activate
(myvenv) $ pip install django
...
(myvenv) $ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: ok yes I didn't realize using the sudo command was releasing me from the venv. One issue I have with this method so far though. I get an error when I try to run manage.py because it is missing the psycopg2 module. Error: You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.

Comment: That's an entirely different question. Try `sudo apt-get build-dep python-psycopg2` to compile the requirements, then you need to actually install pyscopg2 in your virtual environment with `pip install psycopg2`

Comment: ok I got it now, it was just confusing when to go out to the main environment to do something and when to just install it within venv

Answer (score 221):

Had a similar issue but the above method didn't work for me. Clarified it with a rather simpler solution:

`(venv) $ pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt`

**UPDATE:**
This command upgrades all packages that have been explicitly listed in your `requirements.txt` file.

Your `requirements.txt` file is just a list of pip install arguments placed in a file. They are used to hold the result from pip freeze for the purpose of achieving repeatable installations. In this case, your `requirements.txt` file contains a pinned version of everything that was installed when pip freeze was run.

Comment: What does this command upgrades? package's version or something else?

Comment: I had the exact same problem and this worked for me.

Comment: KishorPawar, like I said earlier, it should initiate an upgrade and an install from the requirements.txt file to your virtual environment

Comment: This worked for me as well. Dear Nii, the problem is that we do not understand what "initiate an upgrade" means. It is not referring to the pip version, as a `pip --upgrade` followed by a `pip install requirements.txt` doesn't solve the problem. Maybe you can explain in which case we need to add the flag `--upgrade` to `pip install`

Comment: Don't know what exactly it done, but it worked for me.

Comment: Apologies for the radio silence @LionelTrebuchon. Just to clarify, `pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt` command upgrades all packages that have been explicitly listed in your `requirements.txt`. I've updated my answer to reflect this. 

You can read more on this here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#only-if-needed-recursive-upgrade

Answer (score 49):

try `pip install -r requirements.txt`

It worked for me

Answer (score 8):

`sudo pip install -r requirements.txt` **or** `pip install -r requirements.txt` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem but with a different cause - I had an old version of virtualenv. Before version 1.7 you had to specify the option --no-site-packages when you create the virtual environment to not include global packages.

Two options to fix this, either upgrade your virtualenv:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv --upgrade
virtualenv venv
```

Or use the old one with the no-site-packages option:

```
virtualenv venv --no-site-packages
```

That fixed my requirements.txt file.

Answer (score 1):

Following solution has worked for me :

```
(my-virtualenv) 20:42 ~/MyPf (master)$ pip freeze > requirements.txt | 
(my-virtualenv) 20:43 ~/MyPf (master)$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: What is your problem? Can you specify it!

Answer (score 0):

You have the same problem that I stack with, So the solution is easy:

1. You must check the file path the text takes from it like in a blue circle.
   Run code below:

`cd C:\Users\yk406\.anaconda\yolov7`

Note: path directory is an example paste the path that your environment works in

2. when the first step is done the second one is done by installing file text like in a green circle.
   Run code below:
   `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After

> pip freeze > requirements.txt

you can replace all "==" with ">=" in the requirements.txt file and rerun the command

> pip install -r requirements.txt

**Note**: This may always try to install the latest package. In case your project requires the package version to be freezed to the version in use DO NOT USE.

Answer (score -1):

try: `sudo apt-get install requirements.txt`.
Its work for me but make sure you're in the Osintgram directory first.