# Issues with Installing Flask on Mac

Tags: python, flask

I have been trying to install Flask via `pip install Flask` but I get the following message:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask (from versions:)
>   No matching distribution found for Flask.

Has someone else experienced this issue?

Comment: That's very strange. Are you able to install any other package via pip?

Comment: Yeah, I recently installed virtualenv and had no issues.

Comment: pip install flask -i https://pypi.python.org/pypi

Comment: Maybe check this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167987/python-pip-trouble-installing-from-requirements-txt

Comment: or you may need to upgrade your pip , try "pip install -U pip"

Comment: Felix I tried your first suggestion, this the message I got:  No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://pypi.python.org/pypi/flask/?

Comment: I tried doing a pip install within a virtualenv and that didn't work either.

Comment: What is your Python's version?

Answer (score -1):

This mean your version of Python (certainly 3.X) does not fit with the latest version of Flask and maybe the version for 3.X is still under development. 
I highly recommend you to go to the flask website and download the archive. After uncompressing it, go to the folder in a terminal and type :

```
python setup.py install
```

This should work.