# How to fix error with freetype while installing all packages from a requirements.txt file?

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt, freetype

I ran the following command to install dependencies for a Python project?

```
# pip install requirements.txt 
Collecting requirements.txt
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requirements.txt (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for requirements.txt
```

I searched on Google and found this post: [python pip trouble installing from requirements.txt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167987/python-pip-trouble-installing-from-requirements-txt) but I don't quite understand what the solution was in that post.

Here is my requirements.txt file:

```
# cat requirements.txt 
ordereddict==1.1
argparse==1.2.1
python-dateutil==2.2
matplotlib==1.3.1
nose==1.3.0
numpy==1.8.0
pymongo==3.3.0
psutil>=2.0
```

I then tried to do `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`  and here is the output:

```
# pip3 install -r requirements.txt 
Requirement already satisfied: ordereddict==1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Collecting argparse==1.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached argparse-1.2.1.tar.gz
Collecting python-dateutil==2.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached python-dateutil-2.2.tar.gz
Collecting matplotlib==1.3.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Using cached matplotlib-1.3.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options
    
    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [1.3.1]
                    python: yes [3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23)  [GCC
                            5.4.0 20160609]]
                  platform: yes [linux]
    
    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                     numpy: yes [version 1.11.3]
                  dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.6.0]
                   tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                            WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                            install it after matplotlib.]
                 pyparsing: yes [using pyparsing version 2.1.10]
                     pycxx: yes [Official versions of PyCXX are not compatible
                            with Python 3.x.  Using local copy]
                    libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
                  freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h)
                            could not be found.  You may need to install the
                            development package.]
                       png: yes [pkg-config information for 'libpng' could not
                            be found. Using unknown version.]
    
    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
               sample_data: yes [installing]
                  toolkits: yes [installing]
                     tests: yes [using nose version 1.3.7]
    
    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                    macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                    qt4agg: no  [PyQt4 not found]
                   gtk3agg: no  [gtk3agg backend does not work on Python 3]
                 gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairo to be installed.]
                    gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                     tkagg: no  [TKAgg requires Tkinter.]
                     wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                       gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                       agg: yes [installing]
                     cairo: no  [cairo not found]
                 windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]
    
    OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                    dvipng: no
               ghostscript: no
                     latex: no
                   pdftops: no
    
    ============================================================================
                            * The following required packages can not be built:
                            * freetype
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-don4ne_2/matplotlib/
```

I have already installed `libfreetype6-dev` but the pip command still reports missing this dependency.

```
# apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libfreetype6-dev is already the newest version (2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

Is there an easy way to install all required dependencies for this python project?

Comment: `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: I have updated the output to include the output with -r flag but still not able to install.

Comment: in output you see that it needs `freetype`. It is not python module but system package. You have to install it using ie. `apt-get` on `Ubuntu/Mint`

Comment: Why `-r` because it has nothing to do with `file` ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install packages using pip according to the requirements.txt file from a local directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225900/how-can-i-install-packages-using-pip-according-to-the-requirements-txt-file-from)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

If you are using Linux OS:

1. Remove `matplotlib==1.3.1` from `requirements.txt`
2. Try to install `matplotlib` with `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib`
3. Install all packages again from requirements.txt

   - For Python 2: run `pip install -r requirements.txt`
   - For Python 3: run `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`
4. `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

If you are using Windows OS:

1. `python -m pip install -U pip setuptools`
2. `python -m pip install matplotlib`

Comment: Hi Nilesh, welcome to Stack Overflow. In the future, please include explanation of what the commands you give in your answer do, don't just tell people to run commands.

Comment: Thanks @Nilesh. Did you mean putting 4. before 3.?

Comment: No @Anupam, As in step1, we removed "matplotlib" from requirements.txt, in step4 we are updating requirements.txt with a newly installed package for future use. 
step3 is for installing other requirements from the file.

Answer (score 57):

`pip install -r requirements.txt` for `python 2.x`

`pip3 install -r requirements.txt` for `python 3.x` (in case multiple versions are installed)

Comment: I tried both but still failed. I have posted the output from this command.

Comment: I think there is a required dependency 'freetype' missing for installing MATPLOTLIB. Try installing the dependency and running pip install -r requirements.txt again.

Comment: `pip` won't handle system level dependencies. You'll have to `apt-get install libfreetype6-dev` before continuing. (It even says so right in your output. Try skimming over it for such errors next time, usually build outputs are very detailed)

Answer (score 9):

```
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Referece: [How to install packages using pip according to the requirements.txt file from a local directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225900/how-to-install-packages-using-pip-according-to-the-requirements-txt-file-from-a/54405453#][1])

Answer (score 5):

Python 3:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Python 2:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

To get all the dependencies for the virtual environment or for the whole system:

```
pip freeze
```

To push all the dependencies to the requirements.txt (Linux):

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

([Taken from my comment on another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457612/how-to-use-requirements-txt-to-install-all-dependencies-in-a-python-project/77205454#comment70121709_41457676))

`pip` won't handle system-level dependencies. You'll have to `apt-get install libfreetype6-dev` before continuing. (It even says so right in your output. Try skimming over it for such errors next time, usually build outputs are very detailed.)

Comment: I have already installed libfreetype6-dev. But pip still reports this error.

Comment: Did you see this bug? https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3029/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install all the dependencies inside the requirements file, like `npm install` on a Node.js project

in python you run the following command:

```
pip3 install -r  ./requirements.txt
```

you can use `pip` or `pip3` both work