# VirtualEnv - Should I ignore the venv folder?

Tags: python, git, virtualenv, gitignore

I am starting to understand the advantages of virtualenv. Now, I have created virtualenv folder named `venv` by doing `virtualenv venv`.

Now my question is, Is it useful to push this folder to github or should I add it to `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You should add it to gitignore file.
Then, you should create `requirements.txt` file and populate it with the packages you have installed. Then, on your production server, create the virtual environment and run `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41458329/7825433) to learn more about the requirements file.