# Run python scripts on Jenkins slave

Tags: python, jenkins

I need to run python scripts from the Jenkins slave
As part of this I want to first check if the modules specified in the python scripts are present on the slave python install else install these modules
What would be the recommended approach
a) Convert script to exe (use setup.py)
b) Use a virtual env

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457612/how-to-use-requirements-txt-to-install-all-dependencies-in-a-python-project This might help you