# Updating dependencies of downstream projects using pip requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, packaging, requirements.txt

I have a python package that is used by other applications across an organization, let's call it `buildtools`.

Other applications in my organization have installed this package via

```
pip install git+https://${OAUTH_TOKEN}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/my_organization/buildtools#egg=buildtools
```

I want to add a new feature to `buildtools` that requires a 3rd party package, let's just say its `requests`. So within `buildtools` I add `requests` to `requirements.txt`, import it, and it's all good.

But none of the other applications in my organization have `requests` as one of their dependencies in `requirements.txt`.

When I merge my new code in and update the package, I believe we will run into some `ImportError: No module named requests` errors in the downstream applications that use `buildtools`.

How can I ensure that any application that uses the `buildtools` package gets the `requests` package installed when they get the latest `buildtools`?

In other words, how can I update `buildtools`'s dependencies recursively?

I am aware that I could add `requests` to `requirements.txt` across all the applications in my organization that uses `buildtools`, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

as discussed, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457612/how-to-use-requirements-txt-to-install-all-dependencies-in-a-python-project?rq=1)?

That's the best and most painless way to update/install required packages recursively.

Comment: As far as I understand, this wouldn't work because some of the machines that run my package don't have the 3rd party package I want to use installed on them. So if I update _my_ `requirements.txt` with a package that isn't installed on those machines there will be a "module not found" error. Does that make sense? I could very likely be wrong...

Comment: No, you should deliver your updated ```requirements.txt``` to the target machines and run the code above **from the target machines**. In that case, ```pip``` will automatically download and install the packages as described in ```requirements.txt```.

Answer (score 0):

After further research I found that `install_requires` within `setup.py` is exactly what I was looking for. [This example explains it well](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/master/setup.py).