# creating python auto import script file

Tags: python

I am a new bee in python programming, and want to write a python script file which I can use as an 'import' statement on top of first executable file of my python program which in turn will download all the required dependencies (**pip install** ).

Please help me with it.

Comment: Why do you need it? Just install them once before running your program.

Comment: @sanyash : And what if I want to develop on one machine and deploy on another, I would need dependencies to be installed there as well, Right ?

Comment: You can create a file `requirements.txt` and execute `pip install -r requirements.txt`. It is better than installing inside python code. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457612/how-to-use-requirements-txt-to-install-all-dependencies-in-a-python-project

Answer (score 2):

Try this using the `pip` module:

```
import pip

packages = ['numpy', 'pandas'] # etc (your packages)
for pckg in packages:
    if hasattr(pip, 'main'):
        pip.main(['install', pckg])
    else:
        pip._internal.main(['install', pckg])
```

an alternative would be:

```
import subprocess
import sys

packages = ['numpy', 'pandas'] # etc
for pckg in packages:
    subprocess.call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", pckg])
```

Comment: first solution did not work getting error (    pip._internal.main(['install', pckg])
AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute '_internal')