# Deployment of a Django project on Gandi server

Tags: django

While trying to deploy my django project on my Gandy hosting server, while starting running uwsgi, the uwsgi.log shows an error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

while executing the following line from my wsgi.py file

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
```

here is the full wsgi file:

```
import sys
import os
import os.path

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                                'projectname')))
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'projectname.settings')
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

from what I understand, django is not installed in my virtual environment, but it is listed in my requirements.txt file

```
Django==3.0.6
django-background-tasks==1.2.5
django-compat==1.0.15
django-extensions==3.0.3
django-mathfilters==1.0.0
```

Can anyone pin point where I am missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to use requirements.txt to install all dependencies in a python project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457612/how-to-use-requirements-txt-to-install-all-dependencies-in-a-python-project)

Comment: I have actually restarted a new virtual environment on my local machine, and made sure everything runs fine with runserver.

I have generated a new requirements file    

asgiref==3.2.10
Django==3.1
pkg-resources==0.0.0
pytz==2020.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
    
but still the same problem, django can't be found on the remote server

Answer (score 0):

I realise you've probably moved on from this now!

In case others hit the same issue, you need to deploy your code, not just upload it, for the Gandi Python environment to read requirements.txt and build your code.

See https://docs.gandi.net/en/web_hosting/connection/git.html?highlight=deploy#deploy-your-code

Comment: the user is sharing the server logs clearly. The code has been deployed, but the dependencies are not installed yet. Your comment does not go in the right direction

Comment: You might be right. Just for background, though, I was hitting similar issues to the ones he described when I uploaded my code via FTP (naively expecting the server to run the code as a post-upload action). Committing the code via git then running the ssh deploy command fixed the issue.