# How to actually install python dependancies after cloning a repo

Tags: python

I can't seem to find anywhere that actually shows the command for installing dependencies after cloning a python repository. What is the command for doing so (both windows and mac)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what I understand in your question is some repos provide `requirements` file that provide name of the dependencies with its version.

Comment: I'm new to python as I'm a FED and I'm just looking for a command equivalent to yarn install or npm install but for python

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457612/how-to-use-requirements-txt-to-install-all-dependencies-in-a-python-project