# Creating "virtualenv" for an existing project

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python on which I've been working on. Now I've realized that I need a virtual environment for it. How can I create it **for an existing  project**? If I do this:

```
 virtualenv venv
```

will it work fine? Or do I have to re-create my project, create virtualenv and then copy the existing files to it?

Comment: Your project should provide `requirement.txt` for deployment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comprehensive beginner's virtualenv tutorial?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844869/comprehensive-beginners-virtualenv-tutorial)

Comment: Have you tried it? Was there a problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can just create an virtual enviroment with `virtualenv venv` and start it with `venv/bin/activate`.
You will need to reinstall all dependencies using pip, but the rest should just work fine.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about `virtualenv venv`?  Does that create a `venv` directory in the current shell path or does it create it somewhere in the global filesystem?

Comment: @BigZ Is there a way to do so with virtualenvwrapper? mkvirtualenv?

Comment: For me it worked with `source venv/bin/activate` rather than what is there.

Comment: @alex I just tested it and the venv folder is created in the directory where the command `virtualenv venv` is run.

Comment: For me to activate the venv the command was: venv/Scripts/activate

Answer (score 12):

The key thing is creating `requirements.txt`.

Create a virtualenv as normal. *Do not activate it yet.*

Now you need to install the required packages. If you do not readily remember it, ask `pip`:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Now edit `requirements.txt` so that only the packages you know you installed are included. Note that the list will include all dependencies for all installed packages. Remove them, unless you want to explicitly pin their versions, and know what you're doing.

Now activate the virtualenv (the normal `source path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate`).

Install the dependencies you've collected:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The dependencies will be installed into your virtualenv.

The same way you'll be able to re-create the same env on your deployment target.

Comment: why so difficult? why not create virt env, activate it and freeze the requirements?

Comment: because a new virtual environment won't have the libraries you had previously installed. `pip freeze` the requirements first, then create a new environment, activate it and then `pip install -i requirements.txt`. The last command will run `pip` from the new virtual environment and the libraries thus installed will not be available when you deactivate that virtual environment to work on something else...

Comment: I also recommend the excellent [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io). Then, you can `mkvirtualenv <name>`, `workon <name>` and `deactivate` to get around - which IMHO is much easier to remember.

Comment: This steps are giving me same errors (but for another libriary) as from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167987/python-pip-trouble-installing-from-requirements-txt

Answer (score 9):

If you are using from windows then follow the following procedure:

Step 1: Go to your root directory of existing python project

Step 2: Create virtual environment with `virtualenv venv`

Step 4: Go to /Scripts and type this command `activate`

then if you would like to install all required library , `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

There is something that I would like to add to this question. Because, newbees always have a problem and even once in a while, I do some mistake like that.

If you do not have `requirements.txt` for an already existing `python-project`, then you are doomed. Save at-least 2-3 hours of the day to recover the `requirements.txt` for an already existing `python-project`.

1. The best way to see it through and only if you are lucky, remember from that `python-project`, the most import package. By **most-important**, I mean the package that has **highest-dependency**.
2. Once, you have located this **highest-dependency** package, install it via *pip*. This will install all the dependency of the **highest dependency** package.

Now, see if it works. If it does, Voila !!
If it doesn't you will have get where the conflicts are and start to resolve them one-by-one.

I was working on such a situation recently, where there was no requirements.txt. But I knew, the highest dependency was this deep-learning package called **Sentence-Transformers** and I installed it and with minor conflicts, resolved everything.

Best-of-luck !! Let me know if it ever helped anyone !!